# Python: Comparing values between more than 2 arrays

Tags: python, arrays, max

I have to compare data between 3 or more arrays that look like this:

```
{'Class1': {'diag': {'Class1': array([-138.49760438, -133.93161498, ...]),
                     'Class2': array([-20.78214408, -19.33358523, ...])
                     'Class3': array([-338.81699294, -345.05932059, ...])}
           }
}
```

I want to compare the first 3 values in each array, search for the biggest number and output the corresponding class (1,2 or 3) into a new array. Then go to the second 3 values and do the same. Each array contains around 100,000 values so the process should be fairly fast.

In the above example I should end up with the following array: ['Class2', 'Class2'].

I only found functions that work with 2 arrays but not more. In fact I need it to work with any number of arrays as the classes will increase during my experiments.

I'm looking forward to hearing your ideas!

Comment: Do you need the smallest number or the number with the smallest modulus (like given in your example) or the biggest number (like indicated by the tag max)? :)

Comment: Sorry, just realised I wrote "smallest number" in my post. I need the biggest number, which in my example are -20.78 and -19.33. The numbers are log likelihoods and it is possible that there are also positive values, so it's not necessarily the number with the smallest modulus.

Comment: Is this `array` function/class a custom one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import izip
from operator import itemgetter

# Ignoring the outer levels of the dict and shortening the numbers.
data = {
    'Class1' : [-138, -133,  33, 999],
    'Class2' : [ -20,  -19, 100, 777],
    'Class3' : [-338, -345, 200, 111],
}

lookup    = dict(enumerate(data.keys()))
max_index = lambda ns: max(enumerate(ns), key = itemgetter(1))[0]

# Zip the arrays together.
# For each zipped-set of numbers, find the index of the max.
# Use that index to look up the class name.
classes = [lookup[max_index(ns)] for ns in izip(*data.values())]

print classes    # ['Class2', 'Class2', 'Class3', 'Class1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your arrays have the same length, you iterate from 0 to len(array1). In each iteration i you build a list from the i-th elements of all your arrays. Then you find the biggest element and its index in the resulting list using something like:

```
import operator
index, value = max(enumerate(my_list), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

The index corresponds to the class your max-value is from e.g. 0 --> class1, 1--->class2 and so on. Thus the time-complexity of your solution should be linear in the length of the arrays (and the number of class, depending on the implementation of max).